# Scaling columns of a Sparse Tensor by a vector in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

Assume A is a sparse 2D binary tensor (NxN) and B is a vector (1xN). I want to scale columns of A by B: `A_{i, j} <- A_{i, j} x B_{j}`
I am looking for an efficient way for doing this. Currently I tried two methods but they are too slow:

1. Convert B to the diagonal matrix BD and use `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(A, BD)`. This is going to return a dense matrix and as a result, the method is not efficient.
2. Using map_fn for sparse tensors `tf.SparseTensor(A.indices, tf.map_fn(func, (A.values, A.indices[:, 1]), dtype=tf.float32), A.dense_shape)`. This returns a sparse tensor but it seems one of the `map_fn` or `SparseTensor` functions are the bottleneck.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how you write your `func` (there is multiple way of doing it), so I did not compare it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The faster solution is probably to call `gather` on your tensor `B` to be able to multiply directly the values of `A`. Another option is to use `tf.sparse.map_values`, creating your vector of updates with `tf.gather`.

On a 99% empty sparse matrix of size `1000x1000`:

```
>>> %timeit tf.sparse.SparseTensor(A.indices, A.values*tf.gather(B,A.indices[:,1]), A.dense_shape)
855 µs ± 86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The `map_values` approach:

```
>>> %timeit tf.sparse.map_values(tf.multiply, A, tf.gather(B,A.indices[:,1]))
978 µs ± 73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Compared to the `sparse_dense_matmul` approach:

```
>>> %timeit tf.sparse.from_dense(tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(A,tf.linalg.diag(B)))
26.7 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```